# I have an infinite loop, which i need to break in between, only if any three consecutive values returned from it are same. How to do it?

Tags: c

The code below shows the `rowtotal[0]`, which is the return value I'm getting from an infinite loop for every iteration. I'm trying to break the loop when all three returned values from the costcheck array are the same. This is my code:

```
do
{
 .
 .
 . 
    /*do loop body*/
 .
 .
      costcheck[counter3]=rowtotal[0];

      if(costcheck[counter3-2]==costcheck[counter3] &&
         costcheck[counter3-1]==costcheck[counter3] )
      {
           response=1;
      }
      counter3++;
     printf("\t\t\t Number of iterations: %d \r", stop++);
 }
 while(response!=1);
```

Comment: The line starting with `if(costcheck[counter3-2]==...`is trucated, please correct. And what is the question ?

Comment: are you sure you want to increment `counter3` after assigning `costcheck[counter3]`?

Comment: i have corrected the counter increment.

Comment: but still i am unable to stop the loop...it has went over 50k iterations now. please help.

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of all strange, superfluous variables. You only need to save the result of the previous iteration, together with a counter which you increase each time you find a match, rather than every time in the loop.

```
int counter=0; 
const int COUNT_N = 3;
data_t prev=FORBIDDEN; // a value that rowdata[0] can never have

while(counter != COUNT_N) 
{ 
  ... 

  if(prev == rowdata[0])
  {
    counter++;
  }
  else
  {
    counter=0;
  }

  prev = rowdata[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lundin, but i need to compare three consecutive values, please suggest a way.

Comment: @SaurabhKhati Use the same data type as `rowdata[0]`, obviously... `data_t` is just pseudo-code; I can't know what type `rowdata[0]` is since you didn't include that in your question.

Comment: can you please tell me what you have done with "FORBIDDEN" there?

Comment: After implementing your idea, my program always stops after 3 iterations only, which is not desirable, please suggest a way..

Comment: @SaurabhKhati, either your data is such that it SHOULD stop after 3 iterations, or you've implemented it the wrong way. Lundin's solution works. Post your implementation so we may see it.

Answer (score 0):

just to elaborate on Lundins Answer wich is the way to go in my opinion (would have posted as a comment, but lacking reputation...)
Only thing missing is the actual loop advancement counter (counter3 in your example):

```
int quitCounter=0;  // Counter for quiting the loop on 3 consecutive identical values
int loopCounter=0;  // Your normal rowdata index
const int QUIT_COUNT_N = 3;

#define FORBIDDEN 0xffffff    // or some other value that rowdata[0] can never have 
data_t prev=FORBIDDEN; // a value 

do
{ 

  ... 
  /* do loop body, provide new value for rowtotal[0] on each iteration */
  /* if you need to store the consecutive values returned in rowtotal[0] in costcheck array,
     make sure that it will be big enough - if you only need to break on 3 identical values, 
     you can skip the entire costcheck array as Lundin proposes. */
  ...

  costcheck[counter3]=rowtotal[0];
  if(prev == costcheck[counter3])
  {
    quitCounter++;
  }
  else
  {
    quitCounter=0;
  }

  prev = costcheck[counter3];
  counter3++;

} while(quitCounter!= QUIT_COUNT_N )
```

Comment: loopcounter will always be zero, as i am taking only the 0'th element of the rowtotal array. its just a single value.

Comment: ok, got it, sorry - updated code snipped to better reflect your situation. But it's still Lundins answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an infinite loop, a `if(costcheck[counter-1] == costcheck[counter-2] && costcheck[counter-2] == costcheck[counter-3])` will lead to failure of program, if `costcheck` array has less than 3 elements. You have to be sure that it does have at least 3 elemets in this array.

BUT!!!! counter does not need to be more than `3` because as far as i get it, you want to check 3 most reciently read elements. Which means for comparison, you only need to remember 3 last values that were read.

The exapmple below stores up to 3 `rowtotal[0]` values, and checks if they are equal. If they are, progarm exits, if not, program gets new `rowtotal[0]` to the "end" of `costcheck` array, also the oldest value: here it's `costcheck[0]` is lost.

I can post the code to the example which i made, to show how the logic should work.

NOTE!!! I strongly think Lundin's and Morphine's solutions are by far better than mine.

```
do
{
 .............
    if(counter < 3)
    {
      costcheck[counter] = rowtotal[0];
      counter++;
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if(costcheck[counter-1] == costcheck[counter-2] && costcheck[counter-2] == costcheck[counter-3])
        {
                response=1;
        }
        else
        {
            costcheck[counter-3] = costcheck[counter-2];
            costcheck[counter-2] = costcheck[counter-1];
            costcheck[counter-1] = rowtotal[0];
        }
    }
 }
 while(response!=1);
}
```